# iTextPDF(Java/Android): How to convert Image to bitmap

Tags: java, image, pdf, bitmap, itext

I need to convert the **iTextPDF image** instance to **bitmap** in order to set that bitmap to imageView in android.**(Not android Image instance to bitmap.)** Please checkout the question twice.

```
    Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);
    // Here i need to convert image instance to bitmap object inorder to set it to imageView
    imageView.setImageBitmap(??);
```

**Convert PDF to image using iTextPDF:** and set that image to imageView

```
public void readAndViewPDF(String fileUri) {

    String INPUTFILE = "c:/temp/FirstPdf.pdf";
    String OUTPUTFILE = "c:/temp/ReadPdf.pdf";

    Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(OUTPUTFILE));
        document.open();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileUri);
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfImportedPage page;
        // Go through all pages
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            // Only page number 2 will be included
            if (i == 2) {
                page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(instance);
                // Here i need to convert image instance to bitmap object inorder to set it to imageView. here you can show image on your phone
                imageView.setImageBitmap(??);

            }
        }
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am Sorry, it's not. Actually I want to convert Image of iTextPDF library to bitmap. So please read question once. please!!

Comment: iText doesn't produce bitmaps. It only produces PDF. The `Image` object is used to add Form or Image XObjects to a new or existing PDF. If an existing page of a PDF document is stored inside an `Image` object, it will be treated as a Form XObject (vector data); it won't be converted to a raster image.